# C regular expressions, regcomp

Tags: c, regex

I'm trying to make my way around with regular expressions an check if a String is an integer. I figured the pattern should be `^\d$` and I wrote a function to print an error if the argument is not fit:

```
 regex_t regex;
 void check_int(char *c)
 {
     check=regcomp(&regex,"^\d$",0);
     if (check!=0)
     { 
         perror("4th element on the line is not an integer!"); 
         exit(5);
     } 
     else printf("4th arg is a number.");
 }
```

I'm not sure how `regcomp` works, I used it as I thought I should after checking some examples on the internet.
The trouble is it always says my string is a number, can't figure out why...

Added this, now always returns no match:

```
status = regexec(&regex, c, (size_t) 0, NULL, 0); 
refree(&regex); 
if(status!=0)
{
    perror("..");
    exit(5);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several issues with your example:

- `regcomp` only prepares the regular expression (check [documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/regcomp.html): *"The `regcomp()` function shall compile the regular expression contained in the string pointed to by the pattern argument..."*)
- as per [documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html#tag_09_03_05) I'd assume your regular expression to be `"^[[:digit:]+]$"`
- your strings are terminated by `\n`, so the end anchor didn't match here
- you have to evaluate the [result of `regcomp`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/regcomp.html) in order to evaluate matches (*"If it finds a match, `regexec()` shall return 0; otherwise, it shall return non-zero indicating...."*)
- if a trailing white space is ok for you as well, use `[:space:]` in addition

  ```
  void check_int(char *c)
  {
    int check=regcomp(&regex,"^[[:digit:]+]$",0);
    int status = regexec(&regex, c, (size_t) 0, NULL, 0);

    if (status !=0)
    {
      ....
  ```

Check CodePad for a [full example](http://codepad.org/VdW6Z077).

Answer (score 1):

`regcomp` is used to compile the regular expression pattern, not match it against the input string. To match against the string, you need to use `regexec`. In this case, the return value of `regcomp` is always zero because the pattern seems to be compiled without error.

See [this link](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/regcomp.html) a synopsis for each of the different functions and for usage examples.

Comment: I added: `status = regexec(&regex, c, (size_t) 0, NULL, 0); refree(&regex); if(status!-0){ perror(".."); exit(5);}}` but now it always says it's not a number